# Why aren't device permissions displayed - when using fileImporter and fileExporter in SwiftUI and throwing error

Tags: swiftui

### **Show permission to access Files**

This code works correctly both on the simulator and on the phone, but there are 2 problems

1. Every time when closing or adding a file, both fileImporter and fileExporter generate an error in the console: -
   **The view service did terminate with error: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={Terminated=disconnect method}**
2. Neither simulator nor real phone shows the dialog box whether to give permission to access files.

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isImport = false
    @State private var fileImport: String = ""
    
    @State private var isExport = false
    @State private var fileExport: String = ""
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                Text("\(fileImport.isEmpty ? "" : "Import File -")\(fileImport)")
            }
            ///Buttons
            HStack {
                Button {
                    isImport.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Importer")
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.orange.gradient)
                        .clipShape(.capsule)
                }
                Button {
                    fileExport = makeDocument()
                    if !fileExport.isEmpty {
                        isExport.toggle()
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Exporter")
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.red.gradient)
                        .clipShape(.capsule)
                }
            }
            .fileImporter(isPresented: $isImport, allowedContentTypes: [.json]) { result in
                let result = result.flatMap { accessingRead(from: $0) }
                switch result {
                case .success(let file):
                    self.fileImport = file
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
            .fileExporter(isPresented: $isExport,
                          document: TextDocument(fileExport),
                          contentType: .json,
                          defaultFilename: "MyDocument.json") { result in
                
                let result = result.flatMap { accessingRead(from: $0) }
                
                switch result {
                case .success(_):
                    fileExport = ""
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background{ Color.cyan.ignoresSafeArea() }
    }
   
    private func accessingRead(from url: URL) -> Result<String,Error> {
      let accessing = url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
      defer {
        if accessing {
          url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        }
      }
      return Result { try String(contentsOf: url) }
    }

    private func makeDocument() -> String {
    
    let items: [ExportSomeModel] = [
        .init(user: "Max", about: "Hello 1", age: 21),
        .init(user: "Viki", about: "Hello 2", age: 31),
        .init(user: "Jon", about: "Hello 3", age: 41),
        .init(user: "Rick", about: "Hello 4", age: 51)
    ]
    
    do {
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(items)
        
        let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        
        if let jsonString {
            return jsonString
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return ""
    }
  }
}

struct TextDocument: FileDocument {
    
    static var readableContentTypes: [UTType] { [.json] }
    
    var jsonString: String
    
    init(_ jsonString: String) {
        self.jsonString = jsonString
    }
    
    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        if let data = configuration.file.regularFileContents {
            jsonString = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
        } else {
            jsonString = ""
        }
    }
    
    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
        return FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: data)
    }
}

struct ExportSomeModel: Codable {
    let user: String
    let about: String
    let age: Int
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

I tried to add Privacy to info but no result the device does not ask for permission to access Files